# Select value between two dates and one more value to check in between

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning to programming  video script using PHP. I have the flowing problem :: 
I want to select a video that not been saw by the current user IP in last 24 hours.

I use this sql command :

```
SELECT videos.VideoID FROM  videos,Video_log WHERE Videos.VideoID=Video_log.VideoID Video_log.TIMESTAMP NOT BETWEEN  '$today' AND  '$yesterday' AND Video_log.ip != '127.0.0.1'
```

Datebase Tables :

```
Videos Table :  
VideoID 
VideoURL
```

Table TWO :

```
Video_log Table :::
viewID
VideoID
ViewDate
IP
```

But this sql query return video Id of a video that has been viewed by the same user IP in last 24 hours (today)

More Simple :

**this ip not viewed in last 24 hours and select the videoID**

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is backwards on the `not between`.  The first date has to be before the second:

```
SELECT videos.VideoID
FROM  videos join
      Video_log
      on Videos.VideoID=Video_log.VideoID
where Video_log.TIMESTAMP NOT BETWEEN '$yesterday' and '$today' AND
      Video_log.ip != '127.0.0.1'
```

I also took the liberty of fixing your join syntax, by moving the condition into an `on` clause.  You should also learn how to pass parameters into a query rather than putting them directly into the string.

Comment: That works ... But The IP is stored many times in the table so it will not return any video else by the query